# Error on voting for Moderators

Tags: bug, status-completed

Whenever I try to [vote on a moderator's nomination](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/election?cb=1), I get an error:

> An error has occurred. Please try again later.

Any reason for this? Anyone else experiencing it?

Comment: We've contacted the SE folks and they've got somebody looking into this. We're all seeing the same problem.

Comment: @Caleb - great, thanks!

Comment: Official word is that a fix has been found for the voting issue and they are pushing it out to our site soon.

Comment: And we're live.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to some snappy work from the SE dev team they've rolled out a fix for the bug that was causing this.

Happy voting!

Comment: And now it can't count correctly. Simple addition and subtraction must be too hard....

Comment: @Dan that is assuming the +/- breakdown is correct. I call for a recount (if I loose, but not if I win)!